# Check if a specific custom field exists?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

Is it possible to check if a custom field exists for a given post within the loop? For example, I'm using functions like `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Company', true);` preceded by a `<h4>` tag, but I'd like to check to make sure that there is a value for the custom field "Company" before writing the `<h4>`. Is this possible?

Comment: I love how things asked 11 years ago can still be so relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WP `get_` methods are here to retrieve data, not to display them. You can easily check the var - containing the data - before adding your head tags:

```
$my_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Company', true);
if ( ! empty ( $my_post_meta ) )
    echo '<h4>'.$my_post_meta.'</h4>';
```

Comment: No, it just checks if value is empty.

Comment: @T.Todua The OP asked (in the year 2011): _"[…] I'd like to check to make sure that there is a value for the custom field […]"_, so checking if there is a value is ok. Furthermore, `get_post_meta()` is a simple wrapper for [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/), which returns either an empty string `''` or an empty `array()` if the value is not present. Can you please clarify your statement or do you need any help?

Comment: I wanted to make a note to reader, just that, nothing more...

but the question title tells itself (i havent read the whole topic, just the title), that asked specific problem, and the answer is not 100% soolution to the problem I had (exactly as question ).  Howevermaybe it was satisfying for OP.

Comment: @T.Todua Then you have to clarify what you mean by "exists". As you can read in the answer as well as in the link I provided you in the comment above, `get_metadata()` is sufficient to check if the value exists in the DB.

Comment: yes, `get_metadata` is a different thing. ... p.s. I've never downvoted your answer, just it was my notice, which caused you to make a better comment! thanks

Comment: @T.Todua There is no downvote on the answer :) Anway, `get_metadata()` actually is _the same_ as `get_post_meta()`. The later is just a simplified "wrapper" and internally calls `get_metadata()`. Btw, would you mind if I edit your comment and remove the endless flood of exclamation marks and the bold markup?

Comment: no, remove it, as you wish... I havent looked at `get_metadata()`. I dont know if you understand me, what i mean.. if there exists a key, but it's value is empty, then your function would translate that  "meta doest not exist"... however, i wanted a simple function that will just tell me if that meta even exists.

Comment: Well, if you want the _raw_ value, then you can use `$id_list = [ /* your IDs */ ]; $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $column, meta_key, meta_value FROM $table WHERE ".sanitize_key('post_id')." IN ($id_list) ORDER BY meta_id ASC", ARRAY_A );`. Else, WordPress core will always return either an empty array or an empty string, depending on if you asked for a single value or all values via the functions argument.